# Demidovic - Exercise $1912$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Unless I forgotten something, I believe this exercise cannot be verified. It says to prove that the function
$$ u = \phi(xy)  + \sqrt{xy} \psi\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$

Satisfies the equation

$$x^2 \frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial x^2} = y^2 \frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial y^2}$$

I calculated

$$\partial_x u = y \left(\phi '(x y)-\sqrt{\frac{y}{x^3}} \psi '\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right)+\frac{y \psi \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}{2 \sqrt{x y}} $$

$$ \partial_y u = \frac{2 y \psi '\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+x \psi \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}{2 \sqrt{x y}}+x \phi '(x y)$$

Then

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\partial^2_{xx} u & = -\frac{2 y \left(\left(\sqrt{x y}-3 x^2 \sqrt{\frac{y}{x^3}}\right) \psi '\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)-2 x y \left(\sqrt{\frac{y}{x^3}} \psi ''\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+x^2 \phi ''(x y)\right)\right)}{4x^3} + 
\\\\
& \qquad \qquad + \frac{x \sqrt{x y} \psi \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}{4 x^3}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

and

$$\partial^2_{yy} u = \frac{4 y \left(x^3 \sqrt{x y} \phi ''(x y)+y \psi ''\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+x \psi '\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right)-x^2 \psi \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}{4 (x y)^{3/2}}$$

Yet then after having arranged with the $x^2$ and $y^2$ terms, I do not get zero.

Screen Shot of the Book Page :
[image: 1912]

Comment: I also checked with W. Mathematica.

Comment: @AnneBauval I will add a screenshot. It's taken from Demidovic - Problems in mathematical analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is correct:

When $\phi=0,$
$$x^2\partial^2_{xx}u=\frac{\sqrt{xy}}{4x^2}\left(4xy\psi'\left(\frac yx\right)+4y^2\psi''\left(\frac yx\right)-x^2\psi\left(\frac yx\right)\right)=y^2\partial^2_{yy}u$$
(calculated with WolframAlpha).

The analogue when $\psi=0$ also holds (much more easily), whence the general case, by linearity.

I noticed that your $\left(\sqrt{x y}-3 x^2 \sqrt{\frac{y}{x^3}}\right)$ in $\partial^2_{xx} u$ simplifies to $-2\sqrt{xy}.$

That said, I checked all your calculations and everything is correct, except a $+$ instead of $-$ in front of your last term $\frac{x \sqrt{x y} \psi \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}{4 x^3}$ in $\partial^2_{xx} u.$

Comment: So you confirm there is no error in the request? Ok, then I will check another time again :D

Comment: (I love that book, btw. I found so strange there could be an error, but one never knows. Ah, if you're interested: https://ia801002.us.archive.org/31/items/DemidovichEtAlProblemsInMathematicalAnalysisMir1970/Demidovich-et-al-Problems-in-Mathematical-Analysis-Mir-1970.pdf )

Comment: Good Book , @Numb3rs , It has Answers at the end , unfortunately , 1912 is not given !!

Answer (score 1):

### **Overview :**

**(1)** Let $u_1$ & $u_2$ be Solutions. Then we can see that $u_1+u_2$ is also a Solution , using the linearity here.

**(2)** Here we have 2 Classes of Solutions. Doing the 2 Classes Simultaneously will require more effort & make it unnecessarily complicated.
We can check the Classes Individually , which will then complete the Question by earlier Point 1. This way , we are simplifying the effort , while minimizing the chances for mistakes.

**(3)** It is just playing around with complicated cumbersome calculations , nothing very Deep here. In the End , all terms will line up Correctly , thankfully !!
**It is a Deeper Issue to show that there are no other Classes of Solutions.**

### **Laborious Computations :**

**(4)** Let us check $u_1=\phi(z)$ , where $z=xy$.

$$ \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial x} = \frac{d{\phi}}{d z}y $$
$$ \frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial x^2} = \frac{d^2{\phi}}{d z^2}y^2 $$
$$ \frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial x^2}/y^2 = \frac{d^2{\phi}}{d z^2} \tag{4-1} $$

$$ \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial y} = \frac{d{\phi}}{d z}x $$
$$ \frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial y^2} = \frac{d^2{\phi}}{d z^2}x^2 $$
$$ \frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial y^2}/x^2 = \frac{d^2{\phi}}{d z^2} \tag{4-2} $$

Hence , we have

$$x^2 \frac{\partial^2{u_1}}{\partial x^2} = y^2 \frac{\partial^2{u_1}}{\partial y^2} \tag{4-3}$$

**(5)** Likewise , let us check $u_2=\sqrt{xy}\psi(z)$ where $z=y/x$.

$$ \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial x} = \sqrt{y/x} \psi(z) /2 -\sqrt{xy}\frac{d{\psi}}{d z}y/x^2 $$
$$ \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial x} = \sqrt{y/x} \psi(z) /2 -\sqrt{y^3/x^3}\frac{d{\psi}}{d z} $$

$$ \frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial x^2} = -\sqrt{y/x^3} \psi(z) /4 - \sqrt{y/x} \frac{d{\psi}}{d z} y/2x^2 + 3\sqrt{y^3/x^5}\frac{d{\psi}}{d z}/2 + \sqrt{y^3/x^3}\frac{d^2{\psi}}{d z^2}y/x^2 $$

$$ \frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial x^2} = -\sqrt{y/x^3} \psi(z) /4 + \sqrt{y^3/x^5} \frac{d{\psi}}{d z} + \sqrt{y^5/x^7}\frac{d^2{\psi}}{d z^2} $$

$$ x^2 \frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial x^2} = -\sqrt{xy} \psi(z) /4 + \sqrt{y^3/x} \frac{d{\psi}}{d z} + \sqrt{y^5/x^3}\frac{d^2{\psi}}{d z^2} \tag{5-1}$$

$$ \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial y} = \sqrt{x/y} \psi(z) /2 +\sqrt{xy}\frac{d{\psi}}{d z}/x $$

$$ \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial y} = \sqrt{x/y} \psi(z) /2 +\sqrt{y/x}\frac{d{\psi}}{d z} $$

$$ \frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial y^2} = -\sqrt{x/y^3} \psi(z) /4 + \sqrt{x/y} \frac{d{\psi}}{d z} /2x +\sqrt{1/xy}\frac{d{\psi}}{d z} /2 +\sqrt{y/x}\frac{d^2{\psi}}{d z^2} /x $$

$$ \frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial y^2} = -\sqrt{x/y^3} \psi(z) /4 + \sqrt{1/xy} \frac{d{\psi}}{d z} +\sqrt{y/x^3}\frac{d^2{\psi}}{d z^2}  $$

$$ y^2 \frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial y^2} = -\sqrt{xy} \psi(z) /4 + \sqrt{y^3/x} \frac{d{\psi}}{d z} +\sqrt{y^5/x^3}\frac{d^2{\psi}}{d z^2} \tag{5-2} $$

Hence , we have

$$x^2 \frac{\partial^2{u_2}}{\partial x^2} = y^2 \frac{\partial^2{u_2}}{\partial y^2} \tag{5-3}$$

Comment: Thanks for that Input , @AnneBauval , I have updated the Answer now !

Comment: I managed to solve it already, yesterday, but I will give a $+1$ because of the time and effort you put on this! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How did Demidovich (or others) come up with this answer?

Look for solutions of
$$x^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = y^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}$$
of a simple form, say a monomial: $u(x,y) = x^a y^b$. We need to have
$$a(1-a) = b(1-b)$$
so either $a=b$ or $a+b=1$, with $u(x,y) = (x y)^b$, or $u(x,y) = x \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^b= \sqrt{x y} \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^{b-\frac{1}{2}}$.  Since the equation is linear, any linear combination of the above is a solution.  So at least formally we get
$$u(x,y) = \phi(x y) + \sqrt{x y} \psi (\frac{y}{x})$$